# Align multiple equation lines differently in a single environment

Tags: equations, align

I wasn't sure how to explain it in the title but this is what I would like to do:

[image]

I would like to be able to align the right arrows without having to separate them into two different environments like I did in my code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.25} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Rightarrow k \textrm{ is even } (k=2n)
        \Rightarrow z_k=i^{2n}=(-1)^n 
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is even}
                \Rightarrow z_k=1+0i \\
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is odd}
                \Rightarrow z_k=-1+0i \\
\end{align*}
\vspace{-2cm}
\begin{align*}
    \Rightarrow k \textrm{ is odd } (k=2n+1)
        \Rightarrow z_k=i^{2n+1}=i^{2n}\cdot i= (-1)^n \cdot i
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is even}
                \Rightarrow z_k=0+1i \\
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is odd}
                \Rightarrow z_k=0-1i \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But when I try to do this in a single environment with this code :

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.25} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Rightarrow k \textrm{ is even } (k=2n)
        \Rightarrow z_k=i^{2n}=(-1)^n 
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is even}
                \Rightarrow z_k=1+0i \\
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is odd}
                \Rightarrow z_k=-1+0i \\
    \Rightarrow k \textrm{ is odd } (k=2n+1)
        \Rightarrow z_k=i^{2n+1}=i^{2n}\cdot i= (-1)^n \cdot i
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is even}
                \Rightarrow z_k=0+1i \\
            &\Rightarrow n \textrm{ is odd}
                \Rightarrow z_k=0-1i \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I understand that this is because Latex will line up all the straight arrows (because of the "&") while making the beginning of the longest line start on the right. So I tried adding "&" to the beginning of some lines to make it look the way I wanted but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You can nest `aligned` environments in `align*`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&   \begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow k \textrm{ is even } (k=2n)
    \Rightarrow z_k=i^{2n}=(-1)^n
        &   \Rightarrow n \textrm{ is even}
                \Rightarrow z_k=1+0i \\
        &   \Rightarrow n \textrm{ is odd}
                \Rightarrow z_k=-1+0i 
    \end{aligned}   \\
%
&   \begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow k \textrm{ is odd } (k=2n+1)
    \Rightarrow z_k=i^{2n+1}=i^{2n}\cdot i= (-1)^n \cdot i
        &   \Rightarrow n \textrm{ is even}
                \Rightarrow z_k=0+1i \\
        &   \Rightarrow n \textrm{ is odd}
                \Rightarrow z_k=0-1i \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I was wondering how to align, for example, the right arrow of "k is odd" with the right arrow of "n is odd" of the line above while maintaining the alignment of the right arrows of "n is even" and "n is odd" in the "k is odd" line.

Comment: @IsaKEKW, your are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest that you use `alignedat` environments for the "inner" expressions, to allow you to align the "interior" `\Rightarrow` symbols as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.25} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\Rightarrow \textup{$k$ is even } (k=2n) \Rightarrow z_k=i^{2n}=(-1)^n 
   \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
       &\Rightarrow \textup{$n$ is even} &{}\Rightarrow{}& z_k=\phantom{-}1+0i \\
       &\Rightarrow \textup{$n$ is odd}  &{}\Rightarrow{}& z_k=-1+0i 
   \end{alignedat}\\[0.5\jot]
&\Rightarrow \textup{$k$ is odd } (k=2n+1) \Rightarrow 
           z_k=i^{2n+1}=i^{2n}\cdot i= (-1)^n \cdot i
   \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
       &\Rightarrow \textup{$n$ is even} &{}\Rightarrow{}& z_k=0+1i \\
       &\Rightarrow \textup{$n$ is odd}  &{}\Rightarrow{}& z_k=0-1i 
   \end{alignedat}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I was wondering how to align, for example, the right arrow of "k is odd" with the right arrow of "n is odd" of the line above while maintaining the alignment of the right arrows of "n is even" and "n is odd" in the "k is odd" line.